# Navigation Toolbar HTML changing fontsize and padding with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my first website with HTML just for fun.
https://dennisklad.github.io/BeanyBean/Bean%20Folder/
I have managed to make the navigation bar at the top to shrink by scrolling.
I am having now trouble to make change specifically items in #navbar a,

## navbar a:hover and #navbar a.active.

Whats the code for the Script to not change the whole id="navbar"?

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="navbar">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <div id="nav-right">
                <a href="#search">Search</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "0px 0px";
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.fontSize = "20px";

        } else {
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 0px";
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.fontSize = "30px";
            document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByClassName("a").style.paddingBottom = "100px"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean changing the colors when the user clicks a tab? Just remove the `.active` class from the element that currently has it and add it to the clicked element.

Comment: No. I have the navigation bar that shrinks when you scroll. When it is full size the green bg of the #navbar a is wrong. I want to change that like i did with the general padding and font size in the script but only for the #navbar a, a:hover

Comment: What u except? can u plz explain clearly?

Comment: I have no idea what `Whats the code for the Script to not change the whole id="navbar"?` is supposed to mean or what it has to do with the active or hover state of the items. Could you please explain your problem better?

Comment: On a css file i style #navbar, #navbar a, #navbar a:hover differently. On the script when I make getElementById("navbar") it doesn't change the a. I want to change the padding of #navbar a, a:hover

Comment: If you want to only target the `#naxbar a` your code is gonna get complicated. Better create a `style` in memory and update that on the fly, it will be faster. Unless you can set the CSS in such a way that the changes you want to your `a` are inherited from `#navbar`, so you could still change just a a single value on the parent.

Comment: Make it easy on yourself. Create a new CSS class that contains the different padding and fontSize and other <a> styles. Then just toggle that class on the body. And the reason your code isn't working is because `getElementsByClassName()` return multiple elements instead of one, so you need to loop over them.

Comment: Since all you want to do is make a change after 80 pixels, just add a `#navbar.over80pixels a, #navbar.over80pixels a:hover { /* styling here */ }` to your CSS and then do `window.onscroll = () => document.body.scrollTop > 80 ? document.getElementById( 'navbar' ).classList.add( 'over80pixels' ) : document.getElementById( 'navbar' ).classList.remove( 'over80pixels' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work on the `<a>` tags, is because it's an array-like you need to loop over.

So something like:

```
var links = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByClassName("a");
for ( var i = 0, length = links.length; i < length; i += 1 ) {
  links[i].style.paddingBottom = "100px";
}
```

That could work.

I would prefer to do all the styling inside the CSS though, so the javascript becomes easier.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.body.classList.add( 'scrolled' );
  }
  else document.body.classList.remove( 'scrolled' );
};
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Manjari', sans-serif;
    text-rendering: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

body.scrolled #navbar {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body.scrolled #navbar a {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}


#navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    transition: 1s;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}
#navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: compact;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
#navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
#navbar a.active {
    background-color: #254117;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
#nav-right{
    float:right;
}

header{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

header h1{
    color:#254117;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: "Javanese Text", sans-serif ;
    position:relative;
}

header img{
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 10px double #254117;
}

main{
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 20px;
}

main img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

h2{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: darkolivegreen;
    margin: 80px 0px 0px;
}

a{
    color: darkgoldenrod;
}

a:hover{
    color: darkolivegreen;
    opacity: .7;
    background-color: transparent;
}

footer{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

footer p{
    margin: 0;
}

p.Caption{
    color: gray;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <div id="nav-right">
            <a href="#search">Search</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!--Header element -->
<header>
    <img src="https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/n9xuiJpWFgBZyxbcApPiE_3pWiQ=/2121x1414/filters:fill%28auto,1%29/Lima-Beans-GettyImages-92385531-59c14d28af5d3a0010abf682.jpg">
    <h1>Beany Bean</h1>

</header>

<!--  cmd+"/"  -->
<!--Main element-->
<main>
    <h2>About Beany Bean</h2>
    <p>Beany Bean is awesome! She's the most tasty thing ever.</p>
    <img src="us2bbi9b.bmp">
    <p class="Caption">Beany Bean and her Friends</p>

    <h2>Beany Bean's Characteristics</h2>
    <!--Ordered List-->
    <ol>
        <li>Lovely</li>
        <li>Funny</li>
        <li>Smart</li>
        <li>Yummy!</li>
    </ol>

    <h2>Beany Bean's Friends</h2>
    <p>She has some awesome friends.</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adzuki_bean">Adzuki Bean</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_bean">Mung Bean</a></li>
    </ul>
</main>


<!--Footer Element-->
<footer>
    <p>This site was created for fun. &copy; Bean</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. 
It works. Sorry I just started 2 days ago.
Another question: How can I make the nav bar be in the front?
Because I just noticed that the Head Title over the nav bar scrolls?

Comment: You can use `z-index` to change the order of front-to-back. A higher `z-index` will show an element in front of those with a lower `z-index`

Answer (score 1):

To select `a` tags, you can use `querySelectorAll`. You can also store `#navbar` as a variable, and use ternary operators to make your function more manageable. Though as others have mentioned above, adding/removing a CSS class is by far the most preferable solution.

```
let navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
let links = navbar.querySelectorAll('a');

function scrollFunction() {
  let is_scrolled = (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80);

  navbar.style.padding = is_scrolled ? "0" : "30px 0";
  navbar.style.fontSize = is_scrolled ? "20px" : "30px";

  for(let link of links) {
    link.style.paddingBottom = is_scrolled ? "100px" : "0";
  }
}
```

**Edit:** *to clarify, this answers your question explicitly, though the other provided answers are better solutions than the one you are using. If you are adding/removing batch styles, you should utilise CSS and adding/removing classes where possible.*

*For example (using `classList.toggle` with a second boolean input):*

JavaScript:

```
function scrollFunction() {
  let is_scrolled = (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80);

  navbar.classList.toggle('my-scrolled-class', is_scrolled);
}
```

CSS:

```css
#navbar {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar a {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#navbar.my-scrolled-class {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#navbar.my-scrolled-class a {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I would say that in this case, using `const` instead of `let` for your navbar would make more sense, since you are never expecting these to change or to contain anything but the original selection. (I know, I know, nitpick)

Comment: Fair comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish a multitude of CSS changes is by adding a class to an element that groups it, like adding an `.active` class to your nav. Below is the simplest example of how that could work to change the color of all `a` elements after scrolling 80px from red to yellow:

```js
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', event => {
  (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) > 80
    ? document.querySelector( 'nav' ).classList.add( 'active' )
    : document.querySelector( 'nav' ).classList.remove( 'active' )
});
```

```css
nav { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
nav a { color: red; }
nav.active a { color: yellow; }
main { height: 200vh; }
```

```html
<main>
<nav><a href="#">Hello World</a></nav>
</main>
```

Note: I used `addEventListener` instead of the `onscroll` property on the `window`. This is much more in line with how you should use javascript, but it should work either way.